# fgets breaks when ran for 102 times (C Programming)

Tags: c

I am using this code to read a csv file's data, inputs are the row and column.

It works like a charm until the column 102, and I am pretty sure the problem is the code and mostly sure that the problem is in the fgets part of the code, by the tests I have done. It has nothing to do with loops, it just seems if the whole code is ran 102 times it breaks. I am getting crazy over this, any help would be appreciated. 
 and here is the code:

```
static double csvreader(char a[50],int row, int column) {
char line[50];
char *element;
char *eptr;
double n;
int i;
int j=0;
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(a, "r+");
while(fgets(line, 50, fp)){
    j++;
    if(j == row+1){
        printf("%s",line);
        break;}
}

element = strtok(line, ",");
n = 0.0;
return 0;
   for (i = 1; i < column+1; ++i ) {    
      element = strtok(NULL, ",");}
      n = strtod(element, &eptr);     
      return n;
  fclose(fp);
 }
```

Comment: You should always check if  `fopen()` fails by checking its returned pointer for a null pointer before trying to catch data from the respective stream.

Comment: `return 0; /*unreachable code*/for (i = 1; i < column+1; ++i) ...`

Comment: You `return` before `fclose`. So you might hit a system limit for open files. Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. May I also suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You really need to learn how to consistently indent your code.  The inconsistent indentation makes your code unreadable - **and that includes your ability to read it too**.

Comment: @WeatherVane That was it, I can't believe I haven't notice it. I am a C noob though. Thank you very much!

Comment: As Andrew mentioned: the sooner you get into the habit of making it read like poetry, the better it will be. A decent text editor will make this easy.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I usually do it correctly, but when the code doesn't work and I start editing fast to see where is the problem, chaos reigns. But thank you for pointing it out, I will try doing better

Comment: @WeatherVane Yea, I need to practice more and pay more attention. I am always in a hurry unfortunately. I already use Notepad++. If you have something different in mind I'd love to know

Comment: What does printf("%d\n", FOPEN_MAX); print on your system?